# Android 10 ADB Cheat Sheet

Tags: adb

All of the adb cheat sheets I've found are woefully out of date.
examples of "cheat sheets" with outdated info (for the snarky response about this not being a game or that there aren't any cheat sheets):

https://www.automatetheplanet.com/adb-cheat-sheet/

https://technastic.com/adb-commands-list-adb-cheat-sheet/

https://fazlerabbi37.github.io/blogs/adb_cheat_sheet.html

Does anyone have something as recent as Android 10 or 11 they'd suggest?

Comment: This is not a video game. There is no cheat sheet. Anyone can compile a couple of their favorite commands and call it a Cheat sheet. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: responses like this are the reason I'm reticent to ask for help.

Comment: Hi, while I understand what you want, Firelord's comment also makes sense that: 1) we don't know what you consider as a "cheat sheet", especially if it also includes [`adb shell`](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=code%3a%22adb%20shell%22) which is basically as broad as the Android system itself (moreover if the device is rooted), and 2) answers that only mention external links are susceptible to be dead in the future. Please browse existing [tag:adb] questions to know how it can be used for many things more than these cheat sheets listed.

Comment: Hello ClueLeftInside. ADB is the official open-source protocol available to communicate between Android devices and a host like PC. It's well documented in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) as well as the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/adb/OVERVIEW.TXT). There are no hidden features or commands which may require reverse engineering the protocol/program and develop a cheat sheet. Usually `adb --help` is enough to get started.

Comment: You may also check my old thread on this: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/adb-fastboot-linux-commands-bootloader-kernel-recovery-rom-root-backup.3597181. Community members will be able to help you in better way if you explain what actually you want to do with ADB.

Comment: @IrfanLatif do you want to post your comment as an answer? I will reopen the question and slightly modify the question to make it on-topic.

Comment: @Firelord I don't think I can add anything new to what's already available in documentation and the existing answers here unless the OP needs help with some specific task.