# How to pull within adb shell

Tags: adb

I didn't find a way to use **pull** command within **adb shell**.  I'm using adb from version 30.0.5
so pull command doesn't seem to exist within shell.
`adb pull` doesn't work neither `pull` only. 
Probably it's part of some other command like list packages is

```
pm list packages
```

Thanks

Comment: `pull` alone or `adb shell pull` aren't valid commands. Only `adb pull` is i.e. `pull` is an argument passed to `adb` binary. `adb pull` is run when you are working on a PC and it pulls a file or directory from the connected Android device. When you run `adb shell` you are moved to Android device. Now your commands are not being executed on a PC. So pulling doesn't make sense. // Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @IrfanLatif, I just wanted to copy some files to local system.  It works when I exit adb shell but not from within. <br>
It makes sense not possible to copy if those are commands within the phone.

Comment: That is what Irfan told you `pull` only works from "outside" it is acommand-line option of adb. Therefore if you are in an `adb shell` `pull` is not available.

Comment: Yes @Robert I got it.  It makes sense, Thanks

Comment: Yes clear adb runs locally from terminal ie linux.  `adb shell` directly on the phone, thanks

Comment: `adb help` will give you a list of commands. maybe you find this link(s) helpful to start https://android.stackexchange.com/q/233402